# How to deconflict Prometheus joins with overlapping/colliding labels?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

## Multiple joins of metrics with same labels gets overridden by last group

I am trying to left join from multiple series but having issues with label collisions.

**My query is as follows:**
`server_info{} + on(instance) group_left(version) jvm_info{} + on(instance) group_left(version, commit) application_build_info{}`

The second "version" overrides the first "version". Is there any way to "relabel" at query-time or something similar to MySQL "version as app_version"?

I could not find anything in the documentation, and my google-fu is failing me.

PS. This is in Grafana so solutions using the built in merge/group-by/joins is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## label_replace() function solves the problem

Edit: Thanks to @valyala for explaining the difference between subqueries and functions. Learn something new every day.

For anyone stumbling over this in the future I managed to get it working using `label_replace() function`. Couldn't get it to work with `without(version)` to remove it, so order matters.

```
server_info{}
+ on(instance) group_left(version) jvm_info{}
+ on(instance) group_left(app_version, commit) (label_replace(application_build_info{}, "app_version", "$1", "version", "(.*)"))
```

Comment: Small correction: these aren't real [Prometheus subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) - the [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) is an ordinary PromQL function, which performs transformations on labels.